# RPM drops to 1200 while driving

Tags: rpm

While driving 2004 Chevy HD the RPM without any warning drops to 1200. There has never been a backfire or rough idling,accelerates fine,shifts fine? I have to pull over and restart the engine several because I have lost all power. Once I restart it runs fine. I just replaced the mass air sensor, now considering my next move

Comment: Is this an automatic transmission car?